# Domain\AppGroup authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, web-config, authorization

apologize that there is no code to show, because I'm in investigation level, but is there a way to define authentication just for Domain\AppGroup users to get into **without a screen for credentials input**? can someone refer me to a source or some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to ask yourself the question: what do you want to happen when unauthorized user get access.

and i think the only way is to set windows authentication by adding this to the configuration:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">

</authentication>
```

and allow a page for unauthorized users to redirect to it when the user has not been authorized.

please see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/) also: